# Always Problems Killing Programs

Tags: process

I always have problems killing programs. It's so frustrating. Look at this example below. I simply want to kill the nano process, on id 29409. Why, when I type sudo kill 29409 did it not work?

```
$ ps aux | grep 29409
root     29409  0.0  0.0  71248  3980 pts/1    T    00:06   0:00 sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
computer 29565  0.0  0.0  15948  2236 pts/1    S+   00:13   0:00 grep --color=auto 29409
pc@pc:~$ sudo kill 29409
pc@pc:~$ ps aux | grep 29409
root     29409  0.0  0.0  71248  3980 pts/1    T    00:06   0:00 sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment: You killed the sudo process, which is the parent of the nano process. You should have killed the nano process instead.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to send a Kill Signal **SIGKILL** with a value of 9 which terminates the process with a given Process ID.

```
kill -9 PID
```

Depending on the Job, if it is a background job, you may have to kill it by using `kill -9 $! PID` command.

Alternatively, you can use the `top` command. Run Top command which will list all 
your Processes and then use `k` to kill the process.

You can always get help using the `man` pages. such as `man kill` command will give you the detailed information.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I find using pkill more to the point:
`sudo pkill nano`

Instead of a process id, you give the process name to pkill, and it will attempt to terminate all the processes that match it. As with the `kill` command, you can resort to sending a SIGKILL signal rather than a SIGTERM if the process refuses to terminate gracefully:

`sudo pkill -9 nano`